# How do I maintain the same length of a string?

Tags: python, string

I have a text file where each line represents a record and fields separated with commas

Bank_Account_Id, bank_description, Account_id, Account_description\n

I tried it with:

```
def create_record(bank_account_id, bank_descr, account_id, account_descr):
    return "{0:4},{1:30},{2:4},{3:30}\n".format(bank_account_id, bank_descr, account_id, account_descr)
```

but it varies with length checking len(create_record(params)) according to different data

How I maintain fixed length the a record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a precision in string conversion will force a maximum length regardless of the length of the format target.

```
>>> '{0:4.4}'.format('foobar')
'foob'
```

Comment: Correct. Force a string conversion in order to make it work with integers.